# Multiple sessions with single console in linux?

Tags: linux

Say I have only a single console, is it possible to simulate multiple consoles/sessions?

I'm looking for a linux command/method, not ubuntu/debian specific.

```
#console1
$ ..

#console2
$ console_switch 2
$ ..

#console1 again
$ console_switch 1
$ ..
```

Anything even *like* this available, even as a package?

Found package 'screen', but output isn't maintained between switching.

Answer (score 6):

The `tmux` and `screen` terminal multiplexers are popular for this. It is possible to see several windows at the same time by splitting vertically/horizontally; for example, <kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd> <kbd>`"`</kbd> in tmux. There is even possibility to copy & paste text between windows.

The Emacs editor allows running interactive shells in its multiple buffers – again, with multiple buffers on screen, and with copy/paste between them. So does Vim (using the "`:terminal`" command) and a similar but not quite identical feature exists in Neovim. (In my tests 5 years ago, Neovim's :terminal worked quite well, while Emacs' terminal emulation seemed rather lacking.)

A simpler alternative to tmux/screen is `dtach`, which does not perform full terminal emulation but only allows detaching/reattaching, so the previous output remains. (However, this also means that detaching inside a full-screen program will not work well.)

The Heirloom toolchest [appears to provide](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/man/shl.1.html) a version of `shl`, "shell layers" which were present in Unix SVR3 (and died soon after, but still linger in `stty swtch`). I can't get the toolchest to build at all, however, and I'm not sure the modern Linux kernels have the necessary support for `shl`. If it worked, though, it would be almost exactly like in your example.

Finally, you can have multiple shell processes running as jobs:

```
$ bash
  $ suspend
$ bash
  $ suspend
$ jobs
[1]-  Stopped                 bash
[2]+  Stopped                 bash
```

Answer (score 3):

In GNU Screen you can:

1. split window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>,
2. switch to the new split with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>,
3. open new screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd>,
4. repeat.

Additionally to close current split press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

[GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), and probably many many more.  The term that you're looking for is [terminal multiplexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer) I think.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's exactly what you're looking for, but [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) / [byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu) seems similar. You don't switch with a command, but with a emacs-style key combo. If your distro has it as a package, I'd suggest byobu.

Edit:
Byobu is a usability layer built on top of screen. As far as I know, their's not much that either can do that the other can't, but byobu often makes it much easier.